I want to move my windows/ubuntu dual boot to 2 seperate (new) drives
I currently have a laptop with Windows 11 and Ubuntu 22.04 installed using dual boot on the same drive. I've now come to a bit of a storage issue and want to move to two new seperate (m.2) drives, I currently have 1 512GB drive and probably want to get 2 1TB drives but I have not decided on that yet that is dependent on if this is even feasible. Most guides I find only deal with moving 1 OS, I have no idea how different it will be for my case. My laptop has space for 2 m.2 drives and currently has 1 installed with the dual boot system. How would I go about seperating the OS's to different drives and keeping all my data?

This is a Ubuntu Q&A Support site; we can only help with the Ubuntu part of your question. If it were two Ubuntu systems sharing a drive being moved; I'd not see any differences with moving two systems to a single OS myself; as the important system I'd worry about is the final move which I assume will be the OS controlling the boot process..  ie. I'd just move systems, then fix any booting problems  (windows may have its own issues; but that's off-topic here)

This question is similar to: How to move boot and root partitions to another drive. If you believe it’s different, please [edit] the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

Use Windows tools to move Windows, and totally reinstall Ubuntu and restore from your backup. Backup should be /home, any data in other partitions, list of installed apps to make it easy to restall them and any system files in /etc that you manually edited. I edit grub, but copy into /home for my backups. I also suggest putting old M.2 drive into USB3/M.2 adapter and put full install of Ubuntu on it. Windows will not run from external drive.
